# RASPIVID provides a still image for the duration of -t value

Tags: pi-4, camera, raspbian-buster

Full command string: RASPIVID -o test1vid.h264 -t 10000

File is saved.   Updated Buster prior to installing camera.  Reseated cable, swapped cable, swapped camera each with no change in results.

Command RASPISTILL -o image.jpg works correctly.

Using B4 With 4Gig.

Cameras are both Arducam Day-Night Vision for Raspberry Pi Camera, Wide Angle Automatic IR-Cut Switching All-Day Image, IR LED for Low Light and Night Vision, OV5647 5MP 1080P.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved by a fresh install of Raspberry PI OS and an update.